# Is it true before we were created, Allah asked us do you want to be a angel or want to be a human?

Tags: islamic-basis, creation

Is it true before we were created, Allah asked us do you want to be a angel or want to be a human?

Comment: Salaam and welcome to Islam.SE. Can you provide any further details, like where you've heard this claim come from (Quran, hadith, etc). Generally we expect questions here to show some prior research effort before having been posted here. You answer shows nothing of the sort. Please go through [this help center guide](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidelines for writing good questions.

Comment: Wait, is that theoretically possible? How can you answer a question before you're created?

Answer (score -2):

The following verse has the answer for your question:

> Indeed, we offered the Trust to the heavens and the earth and the
>   mountains, and they declined to bear it and feared it; but man
>   [undertook to] bear it. Indeed, he was unjust and ignorant. Quran
>   (Al-`Ahzab - 72)

**Tafseer (Explanation) Ibn-Kathir:**

> **Al-`Awfi** reported that **Ibn Abbas** said,
>
> **Al-Amanah** means obedience.
>
> This was offered to them before it was offered to Adam, and they could
>   not bear it. Then Allah said to Adam:
>
> > I have offered the Amanah to the heavens and the earth and
> >     the mountains, and they could not bear it. Will you take it on!
> >
> > He said, O Lord, what does it involve!
> >
> > He said, If you do good, you will be rewarded, and if you do evil,
> >     you will be punished.
>
> So Adam took the Amanah and bore it, and this is what is referred to
>   in the Ayah: **وَحَمَلَهَا الْإِنسَانُ إِنَّهُ كَانَ ظَلُومًا جَهُولًا
>   (But man bore it. Verily, he was unjust and ignorant).**

For more information, you can read the whole Explanation at:
http://www.quran4u.com/tafsir%20ibn%20kathir/033%20Ahzab.htm

Comment: But wait I still don't understand. Did he ask us personally? Or did he just ask Adam?

Comment: @Muhammad Ahmad, This ayah you have mentioned is about the Quran, right? The question/choice of being human or angle is about the "free will" according to my knowledge. Dr. Zakir Naik had discussed this thing in a video. I'll share the link if I can find. According to him each human was asked about it, i.e. being a human

Answer (score -3):

I watched a video of Zakir Naik talking about this. From what he said, I understand that we were asked personally.