# Did Allaah ask us if we wanted free will?

Tags: free-will

Recently I saw the video where Dr. Zaakir Naik said Allaah asked each one of us if we wanted free will and that he had asked the like of the mountains but they refused and we accepted. He said proof for this is in [Surah Al Ahzab ayah 72](https://quran.com/33/72):

> Indeed, we offered the Trust to the heavens and the earth and the mountains, and they declined to bear it and feared it; but man [undertook to] bear it. Indeed, he was unjust and ignorant.

So I decided to look for the tafsir of this Ayah in the Ibn Kathir's collection.  From what I read it says Allaah asked Adam if he wanted the Amanah and it also says he asked man. Dr. Zaakir Naik was very specific though, he said Allaah asked us and we have no memory of it. I just want to know where he got his knowledge from?

Comment: How can someone who doesn't already have free will make up his mind about whether he wants it?

Comment: Maybe he created us with free will and asked if we wanted to keep it? or could have given is it in that moment....im just trying to find out if known as sometimes knowledge of certain things have not been given to mankind.

Comment: Allah is usually spelt with just one a.

Comment: This question seems closely related to [Is it true before we were created, Allah asked us do you want to be a angel or want to be a human?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24692).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends on how you interpret the word "amanah" in that verse. Here is one explanation of that word:

> The classical commentators give all kinds of laborious explanations to the term amanah ("trust") occurring in this parable, but the most convincing of them (mentioned in Lane I, 102, with reference to the above verse) are "reason", or "intellect", and "the faculty of volition" - i.e., the ability to choose between two or more possible courses of action or modes of behaviour, and thus between good and evil.(Quran Ref: 33:72 )

Reference: [Muhammed Al Asad The message of the Quran](http://www.islamicity.org/Quransearch/shownote.asp?chap=33&note=87)

Comment: I think that does give it more sense but Dr. Zakir Naik was very specific in saying that Allaah even took away our memory of him asking us and all he gave was that Ayah, no hadeeth or any other Ayat to back that up. So I'm trying to find that information if it exists instead of believing a thing that there is no evidence of in the Quraan or in the hadeeths of the prophet May Allaah's peace and blessings be upon him.